# MERN - Error: Child compilation failed: Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'html-loader'

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, deployment

I had stucking in this problem for a long time and not find out how to solve it. I just want to solve this issue and deploy it.

> MERN - Error: Child compilation failed: Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'html-loader'

Html Webpack Plugin:
  Error: Child compilation failed:
  Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'html-loader' in 'C:\Users\Wachir  awit\Desktop\KaewlomsupAnimalsCare':
  Error: Can't resolve 'html-loader' in 'C:\Users\Wachirawit\Desktop\KaewlomsupA  nimalsCare'

- compiler.js:79 childCompiler.runAsChild
  [KaewlomsupAnimalsCare]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:79:16
- Compiler.js:296 compile
  [KaewlomsupAnimalsCare]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:296:11
- Compiler.js:552 hooks.afterCompile.callAsync.err
  [KaewlomsupAnimalsCare]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:552:14
- Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
  [KaewlomsupAnimalsCare]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
- Compiler.js:549 compilation.seal.err
  [KaewlomsupAnimalsCare]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:549:30
- Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
  [KaewlomsupAnimalsCare]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
- Compilation.js:1323 hooks.optimizeAssets.callAsync.err
  [KaewlomsupAnimalsCare]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1323:35

> webpack.config.js

```
    const path = require("path");
    const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
    const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

    const outputDirectory = "dist";

    module.exports = {
      entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./src/client/index.js"],
      output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, outputDirectory),
        filename: "bundle.js"
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(js)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              loader: "babel-loader"
          }
          },
          {
            test: /\.(css)$/,
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
          },
          {
            test: /\.png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
            loader: "url-loader?limit=100000"
          },
          {
            test: /\.(html)$/,
            exclude: [/node_modules/,require.resolve("./src/client/index.js")],
            use: {
              loader: "html-loader"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        open: true,
        proxy: {
          "/api": "http://localhost:8080"
        }
      },
      plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin([outputDirectory]),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: "./public/index.html",
          favicon: "./public/favicon.ico"
        })
      ],
      resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
      }
    };
```

> package.json

```
    {
      "name": "pth",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "main": "src/server/index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack --mode production",
        "start": "npm run build && node ./src/server/index.js",
        "client": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --devtool inline-source-map --hot",
        "server": "nodemon ./src/server/index.js",
        "dev": "concurrently \"yarn run server\" \"yarn run client\""
      },
      "author": "BB",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.5",
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
        "express": "^4.16.4",
        "express-jwt": "^5.3.1",
        "express-messages": "^1.0.1",
        "express-session": "^1.15.6",
        "express-validator": "^5.3.0",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
        "mongoose": "^5.3.8",
        "passport": "^0.4.0",
        "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
        "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
        "react": "^16.6.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.6.0",
        "react-router": "^4.3.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
        "universal-cookie": "^3.0.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.1.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.0.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
        "concurrently": "^4.0.0",
        "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
        "eslint": "^5.8.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.11.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0",
        "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "nodemon": "^1.18.5",
        "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
        "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
        "webpack": "^4.5.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
      }
    }
```

Comment: But if you check your package.json you don't have html-loader installed as deps, do you?